# How to conditionally push an item in an observable array?

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to `push` a new item onto an `observableArray`, but only if the item is not already present. Is there any "find" function or recommended pattern for achieving this in KnockoutJS?

I've noticed that the `remove` function on an `observableArray` can receive a function for passing in a condition. I almost want the same functionality, but to only push it if the condition passed in is or is not true.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

An observableArray exposes an `indexOf` function (wrapper to `ko.utils.arrayIndexOf`).  This allows you to do:

```
if (myObservableArray.indexOf(itemToAdd) < 0) {
  myObservableArray.push(itemToAdd);
}
```

If the two are not actually a reference to the same object and you want to run custom comparison logic, then you can use `ko.utils.arrayFirst` like:

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(myObservableArray(), function(item) {
    return itemToAdd.id === item.id;
});

if (!match) {
  myObservableArray.push(itemToAdd);
}
```

Comment: Does this do a comparison of all properties on itemToAdd? I only need to test for an Id property.

Comment: This will check that the two are the exact same object.  If you need to check for individual properties, then you could use `ko.utils.arrayFirst`.  I'll add a sample to the answer.

Comment: Excellent tip, but I had to change itemToAdd.id === item.id to itemToAdd.id() === item.id().  I posted my code in the next answer.

Comment: @Rake36 this would depend on whether you think your item id's will ever change and need to be observable.

Comment: @spaceman - what issue are you having === ?  Do you have a sample?  Are you comparing strings to numbers or something?

Comment: yes. yes i was. sorry. :( deleted the comment i posted earlier.

Comment: check should be `myObservableArray.indexOf(itemToAdd) <= 0` instead of `myObservableArray.indexOf(itemToAdd) < 0`, isn't?

Comment: you will get `indexOf` -1 when the item does not exist, so it really needs to be less than zero.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks RP.  Here's an example of using your suggestion to return the 'name' property via the object's 'id' property from within my view model.

```
    self.jobroles = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.jobroleName = function (id)
    {
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.jobroles(), function (item)
        {
            return item.id() === id();  //note the ()
        });
        if (!match)
            return 'error';
        else
            return match.name;
    };
```

In HTML, i have the following ($parent is due to this being inside a table row loop):

```
<select data-bind="visible: editing, hasfocus: editing, options: $parent.jobroles, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: jobroleId, optionsCaption: '-- Select --'">
                            </select>
<span data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: $parent.jobroleName(jobroleId), click: edit"></span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**search a object in a ko.observableArray**

```
function data(id,val) 
{ var self = this;
self.id = ko.observable(id);
self.valuee = ko.observable(val);  }

var o1=new data(1,"kamran");
var o2=new data(2,"paul");
var o3=new data(3,"dave");
var mysel=ko.observable();
var combo = ko.observableArray();

combo.push(o1);
combo.push(o2);
combo.push(o3);
function find()
 { 
      var ide=document.getElementById("vid").value;    
      findandset(Number(ide),mysel);
 }

function indx()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("kam").selectedIndex;
    alert(x);
}

function getsel()
{ 
    alert(mysel().valuee());
}


function findandset(id,selected)
 {  
    var obj = ko.utils.arrayFirst(combo(), function(item) {
    return  id=== item.id();
});   
     selected(obj);
 }

findandset(1,mysel);
ko.applyBindings(combo);


<select id="kam" data-bind="options: combo,
                   optionsText: 'valuee', 
                   value: mysel, 
                   optionsCaption: 'select a value'">

                   </select>
<span data-bind="text: mysel().valuee"></span>
<button onclick="getsel()">Selected</button>
<button onclick="indx">Sel Index</button>
<input id="vid" />
<button onclick="find()">Set by id</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rathore_gee/Y4wcJ/

Answer (score 0):

I would add "valueWillMutate()" before changes and "valueHasMutated()" after them.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var needChange = false;
    var itemToAdd = data[i];
    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(MyArray(), function (item) {
        return (itemToAdd.Code === item.Code);
    });
    if (!match && !needChange) {
        MyArray.valueWillMutate();
        needChange = true;
    }
    if (!match) {
        MyArray.push(itemToAdd);
    }
}
if (needChange) {
    MyArray.valueHasMutated();
}
```