# Knockout.js find email address if already exist in observablearray

Tags: knockout.js

I have ViewModel and one of its properties is an observableArray (receivers). I want to check if an email address already exist to the collection before adding new record to ensure that no duplicate entries will occur. Please help. I tried the approach from here [How to conditionally push an item in an observable array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417270/how-to-find-an-element-in-an-observable-array-in-knockoutjs) but it's not working. It cannot detect if item to be added with email already on the list. I want that if AddReceiver function is called I will validate the newReceiverData email address. Here's my code.

**ViewModel**

```
var ReceiversViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var errorModal = {};

    self.firstname = ko.observable();
    self.lastname = ko.observable();
    self.receivers = ko.observableArray();
    self.newReceiver = {
        receiverfirstname: ko.observable(''),
        receiverlastname: ko.observable(''),
        receiveremailaddress: ko.observable('')
    };
       self.AddReceiver = function () {
        var newReceiverData = ko.toJS(self.newReceiver);
        if (ReceiverValidate() == true) {
        //check if newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress value already exist
            self.receivers.push({
                EmailAddress: newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress,
                FirstName: newReceiverData.receiverfirstname,
                LastName: newReceiverData.receiverlastname
            });
        }
    }; 
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally use the "any" function in the lightweight [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library for this sort of thing when I work with knockout.

```
if (!_.any(self.receivers(), function(receiver) { return receiver.receiveremailaddress() == newReceiver.receiveremailaddress(); })) {
            // push new receiever 
        }
```

You can make the comparison function as simple or as complex as you want.

Comment: I got error "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'receiveremailaddress' of undefined or null reference" I think because receiver is undefined but self.receivers() has items in it

Comment: Do all the receivers in your self.receivers() observableArray have this property? The "any" function runs through them all and looks at this property (the current comparison function I wrote expects this property to be there)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your self.AddReceiver function to something like this:

```
self.AddReceiver = function () {
    var newReceiverData = ko.toJS(self.newReceiver);
    if (ReceiverValidate() == true) {

        //get just the email addresses from your receiver collection:
        var emailAddressInReceivers = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.receivers, function (item) {
                item.EmailAddress;
            });

        //only push into array if email address isn't in emailAddressInReceivers
        if (emailAddressInReceivers.indexOf(newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress < 0) {
                self.receivers.push({
                        EmailAddress: newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress,
                        FirstName: newReceiverData.receiverfirstname,
                        LastName: newReceiverData.receiverlastname
                    });
            }
        }
    };
};
```

This basically flattens your list of receivers to return just the emailAddress, then only adds a new receiver to the array if the email address you're pushing isn't in that list

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy but I got problem. emailAddressInReceivers returns [] even though new items have been pushed to self.receivers. Since emailAddressInReceivers is [] new item with duplicate email is still adding to the collection.

Comment: Yes, it's an array of string (email addresses) that are currently in self.receivers. The next line basically says if emailAddressInReceivers DOES NOT contain newReceiverData.receiveremailaddress then add it

Comment: Please note that indexOf() is not supported in IE8 or lower. 
(see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3629211/1016885)

Comment: Could use ko.utils.arrayIndexOf instead, which is supported in IE8

Comment: These are all great examples. Please consider using arrayFirst. See here for documentation: 
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html