# How to use underscorejs _.where on an knockoutjs observable array?

Tags: knockout.js, underscore.js

I need to find a report among the reports observable array by Id. How am I supposed to write the `underscore` statement?

I am using:

```
_.where(reports(), {id:data.ReportId})
```

and

```
_.where(reports(), {id:ko.observable(data.ReportId)})
```

It always return an empty array.

Then I find out some `underscoreKO.js`, but it still won't work. Can someone help me? Thanks.

---

There is another similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417270/how-to-find-an-element-in-an-observable-array-in-knockoutjs?rq=1), but they are not exactly the same. `ko.utils.arrayFirst` can locate the item, but won't help me update it.

---

The correct answer came from Daniel A. White, with a little change. Thank you.

One correction:

```
var record = _.filter(reports(), function (item) { return item.id() == data.ReportId; })
if (record.length > 0) {
    _.first(record).reportStatus("Approved");
}
```

I find it has to be `item.id()` instead of just `id()`. But a million thanks to Daniel!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that will work since `id` in your reports is an observable.

You should use `filter`.

```
_.filter(reports(), function(item) {return id() == data.ReportId; })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` in your reports is observable, you might need to just use `filter`:

```
var filteredReports = _.filter(reports(), function (report) {
    return report.id() === data.ReportId;
});
```